# a qt slot in the same thread can be executed concurrently

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5

My goals: understand better Qt and avoid race condition :)

I have a slot connected to a `QTimer::timeout` (instancied in the same thread) and that could be also called by a slot connected to `WebSocket::textMessageReceived`.

What happen if this two signals are emitted in the same time?

And more, if the same slot is connected to two `QTimer::timeout` with the same interval, the slot run twice concurrently?

Comment: The slot is executed in the thread where the object lives (except you use Qt::DirectConnection but this is a hack) so no concurency possible.

Comment: They can't be emitted at the same time if all the objects lives in the same thread. Otherwise, slot calls will be queued and launched sequentially. One exception - forced Qt::DirectConnection. In this case slot can be called concurrently.